# How to refresh a part of the DOM HTML when querying a foreign django view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, django-views

**Hello Awesome People!**

So many questions on **StackOverflow** are about *"How to refresh dom via jquery (`from the same view/url`)"* It's not what I'm looking for.

With a website that large of its parts are running with ajax, I wonder how  to refresh a part of the HTML DOM when querying a **foreign django view**.

Let me be clearer with some examples:

I have that view that sends `all_users` to template

```
def usersList(request):
    all_users = User.objects.all()
    return render(request,'administration/users-list.html',{'all_users':all_users})
```

In the template I loop through `all_users`... The 2nd `<span>` reflects the `activation state` of the user

```
{% for u in all_users %}
    <span>{{forloop.counter}}.- {{u.name}} <span>
    <span id='user_{{u.id}}_state'>
        <button data-id='{{u.id}}' type='button' class='css-btn btn-circle'>
        {% if u.is_activate %} Active{% else %}Inactive{% endif %}
        </button>
    <span>
{% endfor %}
```

With jquery, I send a request to a specific view responsible only to `activate` or `deactivate` the account of the user. We can `activate/deactivate` user in many parts of the website, that's why I do so in a different view.

Here's the view:

```
def deactivateUser(request):
    user = request.user

    if user.has_perm('is_admin') and request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
        id_user = request.POST.get('id')
        targeted_user = get_object_or_deny(User,id=id_user)
        # get_object_or_deny is my own function
        it will get the object or raise PermissionDenied otherwise

        if targeted_user.is_activate:
            targeted_user.is_activate = False
            state = 'deactivated'
        else:
            targeted_user.is_activate = True
            state = 'activated'
        targeted_user.date_update_activation = NOW() # own function
        targeted_user.save()

        return JsonResponse({'done':True,'msg':'User successfully %s' %s state})
        # Here we return a JsonResponse
    raise PermissionDenied
```

So now, how can I refresh the Dom with following jquery stuff to get the current state of each user

```
$(document).on('click','.btn-circle',function(){
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $.ajax({
        url:'/u/de-activate/?ref={{ request.path }}',
        type:'post',
        data:{
            csrfmiddlewaretoken:"{{ csrf_token }}",
            id:id,
        },
        success:function(response){
            $("#user_"+id+"_state").replaceWith($("#user_"+id+"_state",response));
            if(response.created) alert(response.msg);
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("An error has occured, try again later");
        }
    });
});
```

> Note that `all_users` is required to loop through. `deactivateUser()` return a Json response, even though it doesn't returned it, it will not matter.

Comment: what you got when you refresh the dom the way you do?

Comment: The targeted part `$("#user_"+id+"_state")` becomes blank, make sense because the response is `Json`, not a `string html response`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send http response, not json.

First, just move your html that want to change. in this situation,

```
    {% for u in all_users %}
    <div id="user-part">
        <span>{{forloop.counter}}.- {{u.name}} <span>
        <span id='user_{{u.id}}_state'>
            <button data-id='{{u.id}}' type='button' class='css-btn btn-circle'>
            {% if u.is_activate %} Active{% else %}Inactive{% endif %}
            </button>
        <span>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Then save it i.e. `user_part.html`

Second, make your view return `HttpResponse` with that html, and context. You can use either `HttpResponse` or `render_to_response`. I recommend `render_to_response`.

```
context = {
    'all_users': all_users,
}
return render_to_response(
    'path_to/user_part.html',
    context=context,
)
```

Third, you just change script for replacing your html.

```
success: function(response){
    $('#user-part').html(response);
    prevent();
}
```